# Internal Server Error from PostAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have the method below which posts data to a URL

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(string method, string data, bool isJson = true, long key = 0)
    {
        IActionResult result;
        try
        {
            var proxyUrl = await EstablishProxyUrlAsync(method, key).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var content = isJson ? new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") : new StringContent(data);

            var response = await this._httpClient.PostAsync(proxyUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            result = await ProcessResponseAsync(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, this.GetType().Name + ": Error in PostAsync");
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

As you can see I **am** setting ContentType, loads of posts about dealing with StringContent say about using this method.

However, I just get this back

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2018 19:19:35 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

This is obviously a pretty useless response in terms of seeing what the problem is

The method being called is below

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync(StringContent content)
{
    var myJson= await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var object= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(myJson);
    var result = await _service.AddAsync(object).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I have included HttpPost

Does anyone know what could cause this?

I am using service fabric and this URL is one on a partition, but I dont think this is the problem as this routing works in other areas

Paul

Comment: did you step through the code? possible `content` argument on action could be null

Comment: I cant get to the last method, my breakpoint is not hit.  However content.Header.ContentLength is set (931) in the PostAsync method

Comment: does not matter if content length has a value. if model is not bind by model binder it will be null.

Comment: Have you tried calling your api directly, iusing fiddler for example?  Should also fail. `StringContent` is for building response content. You can read from request stream, but it is easier to use the model binding.

Comment: I cant do that easily as the api is within my cluster.  Im hoping model binding will work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method being called should be refactor to follow proper syntax and pass the model to the action and have the model binder populate it with the incoming data.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddAsync([FromBody] MyObject model) {
    var result = await _service.AddAsync(model);
    return result;
}
```

with the assumption that `_service.AddAsync(model);` returns `IActionResult` when awaited

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Ah thanks I forgot to add [FromBody] I will try that

Comment: Adding [FromBody] has not worked. I will see if I can change to using an object now instead of StringContent